# RDP with root to Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, remote-desktop

Im working with GNOME Ubuntu 22.04.
I opened the option to connect to the RDP in the setting and I able to connect without any problem with regular users.
I want to connect with "root" also.
I already enable root to login to the gui, and it works.

How am I enable the option to connect with rdp to root?

Thanks.

Comment: It is not recommended to log in as `root`. Log in as a regular user and use `sudo` only for tasks that need `root` permissions. This helps to prevent mistakes. If you do something wrong with `root` permissions you can make your system unusable.

Comment: Thanks for the advice . But I would still like to now if there is an option to enable root with RDP

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, and nobody else seems to know or to care how to use the system in a non-recommended unsafe way. Logging in as `root` locally is also not recommended. Using a graphical desktop environment as `root` is even more dangerous than a console login.